# Debugging a DLL with GDB under WSL

Tags: dll, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Sorry if that has been asked already, searching didn't yield any results...

I installed WSL to debug some legacy code that comes as an .exe for which I don't have sources (yet) and a .dll which I can access. The whole thing has been built using mingw32 tools and I figured that it should be easier to work with the *ix (DWARF or whatever) debug symbols instead of messing around trying to convert those to PDB but I might be wrong...

Now I want to debug the dll using gdb under the WSL (Ubuntu 20.04 in case that is relevant). I can load the dll, load the symbols, set a breakpoint somewhere, load the exe and run. Then I get the following messages

```
warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x1234567
```

and won't get any further. The dll itself is compiled for arch=i586.

Funny enough, if I try the same with a dummy program I get the same warning but can proceed normally.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your exe is build by mingw, use gdb under mingw. If your exe is build by cygwin, use gdb under cygwin.